# My own mini-framework is not compatible with some projects

Tags: javascript, compatibility

I failed to create a mini-library with some useful functions that I have found over the Internet, and I want to use them easily by just including a file to the HTML (like jQuery).

The problem is that some vars and functions share the same name and they are causing problems.

Is there a better solution to this instead of giving crazy names to the vars/funcs like "bbbb123" so the odds that someone is working with a "bbbb123" var is really low?

Comment: The solution is to do something like what jQuery does: encapsulate all your behaviors inside a module so that you only use up one symbol in the global namespace

Comment: Pointy, please create a short example, I would be eternally happy if you could do that, (because I am not 100% satisfied with the namespace solutions I am getting)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can create an object as a namespace. There are several ways to do this, syntax-wise, but the end result is approximately the same. Your object name should be the thing that no one else will have used.

```
var MyLibrary = {

    myFunc: function() { /* stuff */ }

};
```

Just remember, it's object literal syntax, so you use `label : value` to put things inside it, and not `var label = value;`.

If you need to declare things first, use a wrapping function to enclose the environment and protect you from the global scope:

```
var MyLibrary = (function() {

    var foo = 'bar';

    return {
        myFunc: function() { /* stuff */ }
    };

})(); // execute this function right away to return your library object
```

Comment: what is the usage, how can I use them :O?

Comment: @TuxedoKnightChess Just call them with `MyLibrary.myFunc()`

Answer (score 2):

I would put all of your functions and variables into a single object for your library.

```
var MyLibrary = {
  myFunc: function() {
    //do stuff
  },

  myVar: "Foo"
}
```

There are a few different ways of defining 'classes' in JavaScript. [Here](http://www.phpied.com/3-ways-to-define-a-javascript-class/) is a nice page with 3 of them.

Answer (score 2):

You should take one variable name in the global namespace that there are low odds of being used, and put everything else underneath it (in its own namespace).

For example, if I wanted to call my library AzureLib:

```
AzureLib = {
    SortSomething: function(arr) {
        // do some sorting
    },
    DoSomethingCool: function(item) {
        // do something cool
    }
};

// usage (in another JavaScript file or in an HTML <script> tag):
AzureLib.SortSomething(myArray);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could put all of your library's functions inside of a single object.  That way, as long as that object's name doesn't conflict, you will be good.  Something like:

```
var yourLib = {};

yourLib.usefulFunction1 = function(){
    ..
};

yourLib.usefulFunction2 = function(){
    ..
};
```